# Phaser tween doesn't work inside of update function

Tags: javascript, logic, phaser-framework

My tween doesn't start inside of the update() function. I don't really know how to realize it otherwise. Here's what I'm doing:

I'm working on turn-based combat. Inside of the update() function I have a switch(currentState) which switches states from START to PLAYERCHOICE to ANIMATIONS etc.

So inside of the ANIMATIONS part of it I have:

```
gameState.prototype = {

  preload: function() {  
    // preload game assets
  },

  create: function() {
    // create game objects
  }

  update: function() {
    PlayerAttack_Animation();
  },
}

function PlayerAttack_Animation() {

  player_dealt_dmg_alpha_tween = game.add.tween(player_dealt_dmg_txt).to( { alpha: 0 }, 1000, "Linear", true);
  player_dealt_dmg_y_tween = game.add.tween(player_dealt_dmg_txt).to( { y: (enemy.y-90) }, 1000, "Linear", true);

 }
```

It worked inside of a listener function when was called from create() function.

Comment: Shouldn't the `PlayerAttack_Animation()` function be inside the `gameState`?

Comment: @B.Naeem No? Not that I know of... All other functions are also outside of gameState and are being called without issues. The problem is not in calling it I think, but in actually rendering. Because update() is being called every tick, so maybe the tween constantly restarts and therefore doesn't move.. But that's my theory. I'm not even sure how to do it. As a separate even_listener outside of update, it works just fine

Comment: yeah maybe that is what is happening. Try and display a log inside the tween function and check the console if it is being called. If it is indeed being called but it keeps resetting due to the update function being called before its execution finishes would be to maintain a `boolean` variable in your tween function which checks if the tween has completed. If it has then the function should be executed again, otherwise it won't.

Comment: i agree with that play with console.log and see it it log something in PlayerAttack_Animation